# when importing from pynput.keyboard import Listener getting error [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, debugging, operating-system, pynput

while executing the below code i am getting an error

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener 
def wrtie_to_file(key):

key_data = str(key)
with open("logs.txt",'a') as f:
    f.write(key_data)
with Listener(on_press = wrtie_to_file) as l:
l.join()
```

OUTPUT-

```
C:\Users\star\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\star\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\main.py': [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: Please edit your question and insert the code and the error message as text, not as an image.

Comment: @MasoudKeshavarz thanks , could now please help me